# Jenkins label not recognised for node

Tags: jenkins, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy to a node using jenkins, and even though the job recognises the node, when attempting to run the job turns to pending and tries to look through every environment for the node.

I've recently set up a new jenkins job to deploy a spring batch project onto a server. We already have a job for another project to deploy to the same node, so the node is recognised, and when viewing that build it does list three jobs.

However, when trying to run this new job, it attempts to find the node against all of our existing labels (see code below for example output), but doesn't find the actual node it should be running on.

The example I've used is NEW_BATCH_DEPLOYMENT, this is listed with having 3 jobs on the environment, two are new jobs that haven't been run, one is a job that ran just before attempting the batch job and succeeded.

For debugging, we've attempted to deploy with NEW_BATCH_DEPLOYMENT_2, which gives us an error for "can't find node with label NEW_BATCH_DEPLOYMENT_2", and if we remove the node name, it simply runs with one of our default nodes.

Has anyone seen something similar to this, or have any idea of a solution? I've compared the new job against the working job and the only differences are the file paths for where to deploy to, and the git url to pull the projects down.

Jenkins version : 2.181

(pending—; ‘Env_1’ doesn’t have label ‘NEW_BATCH_DEPLOYMENT’; ‘Env_2’ doesn’t have label ‘NEW_BATCH_DEPLOYMENT’; ‘Env_2’ doesn’t have label ‘NEW_BATCH_DEPLOYMENT’;

I'd expect it to deploy to the node, but it just hangs with pending and doesn't reach the stage where it would output to the jenkins console.

As mentioned the other job with similar configuration works.

Comment: If your nodes are Docker containers and as you say, the other jobs on the same node run fine, then sometimes there might be a delay of few seconds or more until Jenkins spawns a new container and gets it ready, displaying these generic messages. If the wait is unusually longer, check if there are too many stray containers sticking around in the Docker host caused by aborted builds, etc. maxing out the cap that has been set for the number of concurrent containers allowed. There could be other possible reasons but since other builds work fine, we can defer them for a while.

Answer (score 0):

So just to confirm, that is the exact label you are using? "NEW_BATCH_DEPLOYMENT"? Or is that the name of the node? THe Label should be set in the Node configuration, under the "Labels" section, with no extra characters other than the label name.

I've had issues where it can't find the node label if there are spaces in the label (either on the job side or on the configuration/set-up side)

If the labels are correctly set up, it could also be that the node assigned to "NEW_BATCH_DEPLOYMENT" is offline.

Comment: If you look at the job, under the label expression you get  
Label NEW_BATCH_DEPLOYMENT is serviced by 1 node, so it recognises that it's valid.
As mentioned, if you click on the node it lists other jobs, and we did a deployment of another project to that node around 10 minutes before running attempting to run this one. That one was successful so the node shouldn't have any problems.
Both jobs just aim to unzip a different git repo, all the other variables are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, we fixed it.

It seems that on a node level you can set restrictions on jobs, so when the node was set up, it was restricted to only run the one job. The issue is, the only way you can see this is using an admin login.

If anyone else has this issue I'd highly recommending checking the settings on the node to see if the node itself has any restrictions, rather than the job. You will need a Jenkins Admin to do this.